# URL encoding in wso2 esb ascii should be + for space instead of %20

Tags: java, http, url, wso2, wso2-esb

we are invoking GET URL of other service where we need to send query param so we have implemented the same.

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
below is the URL
actual query param is : Welcome To FACEBOOK INSTA

```
  <http uri-template ="http://********:8080/invokehttp/httpublish?PUSH_TYPE={uri.var.pushtype}&amp;SERVICE_CODE={uri.var.servicecode}&amp;MSISDN={uri.var.msisdn}&amp;PUSH_TEXT={uri.var.pushtext}&amp;USER_ID={uri.var.username}&amp;PASSWORD={uri.var.password}" format="rest">

"http://10.135.*.*:8080/invokehttp/httpublish?TYPE=2&SERVICE_CODE=889998&MSISDN=777777&PUSH_TEXT=Welcome%20To%20FACEBOOK%20INSTA&USER_ID=Admin&PASSWORD=******
```

but client expecting "+" in place of spaces how we can achieve it .

client  expectation message is

```
 "http://10.135.*.*:8080/invokehttp/httpublish?TYPE=2&SERVICE_CODE=889998&MSISDN=777777&PUSH_TEXT=Welcome+To+FACEBOOK+INSTA&USER_ID=Admin&PASSWORD=******
```

we have tried in wso2 esb but not able to achieve it in any way.

Please suggest how we can send "+" instead of "%20"

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).   How do you invoke the `GET` to the other service.   Unless we know how you are doing it, it is hard to suggest corrections to encode spaces differently.

Comment: its just get call from ESB to other service where we need to send URL query parameter in that one of the parameter has spaces

Comment: What are you doing to encode the spaces?

Comment: nothing wso2 ESB itself adding it

Comment: So this URL won't work when you get it as input?

Comment: any suggestion how to achieve it .

Comment: Do you know is doing the escaping of the parameters for the `uri-template`?